# Crawling protected sites with Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler, puppeteer

I am trying to crawl some sites, e.g. http://www.faintinggoatdc.com/food/dinner-menu/ with puppeteer, but I am still blocked. Not every single time, but most of the times, and definitely after just one second page, even when I click on it manually myself in Chromium. This is the error message I get, with a StackPath logo:

> "Sorry, you have been blocked. This website is using a security
>   service to protect itself from online attacks. You performed an action
>   that triggered the service and blocked your request."

This is my code, along with the problematic url. Any idea??

```
async function getPuppeteer(url) {
    console.log("Launching Puppeteer for " + url)
    let  browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, slowMo: 250, width: 1280, height:900})
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    page.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36")
    let resp = await page.goto(url) 
    let content = await page.content()
    //browser.close()
}
await getPuppeteer("http://www.faintinggoatdc.com/food/dinner-menu/")
```

Needless to say the *request* doesn't work either.

Moreover, despite me specifying a width of 1280, it opens it in a 785px frame.

Comment: You're trying to crawl a site that does not want to be crawled, and even invested in network security to prevent crawling. This has nothing to do with your code, so I hope you're not here to ask us how to bypass a site's security features.

Comment: There's ways to detect puppeteer, check the requests and see if they're sending back info on your plugins, navigator or window object.

Comment: Their robots.txt is the following: "User-Agent: *
Crawl-Delay: 5

User-agent: *
Disallow: /wp-admin/
Disallow: /wp-includes/"
If they did not want to be crawled, they would specify it there.

Comment: You're probably being blocked because of too many requests. Change your ip address (use proxy/vpn)

Comment: It blocks on the *second* request! Pupeteer opens it in Chromium (when headless=false). If I click on any link of that site after, say, 1 minute, it blocks! In Chrome (my regular browser), there is no issue at all (the screen flashes because of Javascript activity), and even with Chromium, but not started from Puppeteer. It's really the Puppeteer browser that creates the block.

Comment: That's not issue with puppeteer. The site is very welly protected. They caught your ip address that you used to crawl that site. My suggestion is to always use VPN when do scraping projects also if you know that the site is protective then you can disable the extensions on puppeteer headless browser. So that the site can't get you using automation tool